# MySQL Bulk Insert Ignore

Tags: mysql, insert, innodb, bulkinsert, myisam

I've a few questions regarding the MySQL bluk insert Ignore statement, both for InnoDB and MyISAM.An example:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO table(`reference`) VALUES ('1','2','3')
```

Reference is an unique key also.

1. Is a bulk insert atomic? So if I send this to the database can I be assured that no other inserts occur in between this statement?
2. A batch insert returns the value of the First ID inserted of the batch. However, what happens if the first insert happens to be a duplicate (do I get a 0 as a return value or is the next (successful insert returned, I couldn't find this in the docs)

Kind regards,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Many things are going on here...

- Syntax error:  You have 1 column, but 3 values.  Perhaps you meant this instead?  `... VALUES (1), (2), (3)`.
- After that fix, your one statement is essentially equivalent to three 1-row `INSERT IGNOREs` wrapped in a transaction (if using InnoDB).
- Because of `IGNORE`, any duplicate key will not abort the insert.
- The VARIABLE `innodb_autoinc_lock_mode` controls what happens with `AUTO_INCREMENT` during a multi-row `INSERT`.  Need to know its values to answer this question completely.  By default, the `AUTO_INCREMENT id` will be bumped up by 3, regardless of how many `reference` values are duplicates.  This leads to a surprise "burning" of ids.  (And eliminates your question about what the "First ID" is.)
- Nothing is "atomic" in a non-transactional engine such as MyISAM.  In particular, ...
- With MyISAM, a multi-row write (insert/update/delete) that is interrupted (eg, by power failure), may have done some of the rows -- you cannot tell how many.  (This is an important reason to avoid MyISAM.)

Answer (score 0):

A single MySQL query, be it `SELECT`, `INSERT` or anything else, should be atomic insofar that the statement will either completely succeed and finish, or fail and be rolled back.  This does not mean that your `INSERT` will run in isolation or that it will be fully ACID compliant, but it should be atomic.

> A batch insert returns the value of the First ID inserted of the batch.

I don't know what tool or interface you are using, but the [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/insert.html) says otherwise:

> If you use an INSERT ... VALUES statement with multiple value lists or INSERT ... SELECT, the statement returns an information string in this format:
>
> Records: 100 Duplicates: 0 Warnings: 0

In JDBC, for example, the API returns the number of records affected by the `INSERT` operation, not the ID of the first row inserted.